# What do I actually Do with the winning neuron of a Self Organizing Map?

Tags: som

I've reviewed weeks worth of material and everyone stops at identifying the winning neuron and plotting the SOM.

However, how do I actually use this output?

Answer (score 0):

Unsupervised SOMs are mainly used for clustering and visualization.

**Clustering:** Find datapoints which have their winning neuron close to each other. These datapoints share similarities and might belong to the same cluster or class.

**Visualization:** Plot the SOM grid and try to include the information about the winning neuron per datapoint into it. Examples are the [World Poverty Map](http://www.cis.hut.fi/research/som-research/worldmap.html), RGB clustering, and this [blobs example](https://github.com/felixriese/susi/blob/master/examples/SOMClustering.ipynb).